# iOS - How to create a Dictionary of GMSPolygons associated with their GMSMutablePath from JSON file

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am currently working with the iOS `Google Map SDK`, and I want to draw some polygons on my map.

More precisely, I have a JSON containing different lat/long points for a specific department.

I am able to draw a `GMSPolygon` by creating a `GMSMutablePath` composed by only a few points, like presented in the Google Documentation.

What I can't achieve on the other end, is to make it generic.

Let me show you some code.

```
{"01": [[51.01, 2.07], [50.99, 2.12], [51.01, 2.11], [51.03, 2.15], ...], "02": [[50.51, 1.64], [50.51, 1.66], ...]}
```

I have this JSON file, containing thousands of position points for a specific department. I have shorten it so that you can only see the format of the JSON Object.

Here is my parsing :

```
-(void) parseJsonDept {
    NSString *jsonFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dept" ofType:@"json"];
    if (!jsonFilePath) {
        NSLog(@"Not a valid FilePath");
        return;
    }

    NSString *myJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:jsonFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    if (!myJSON) {
        NSLog(@"File couldn't be read!");
        return;
    } 

    NSError *error =  nil;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[myJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:&error];
}
```

Very straightforward, and now I don't know how to handle it.

I have this piece of code from the Google Documentation in order to draw a Polygon.

```
-(void) drawPolygon {
    // Create a rectangular path
    GMSMutablePath *rect = [GMSMutablePath path];
    [rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.01, 2.07)];
    [rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(50.99, 2.12)];
    [rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.03, 2.15)];
    [rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.01, 2.18)];

    // Create the polygon, and assign it to the map.
    GMSPolygon *polygon = [GMSPolygon polygonWithPath:rect];
    polygon.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.05];
    polygon.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    polygon.strokeWidth = 2;
    polygon.map = _mapView;
}
```

My question is how to create a Dictionary of `GMSPolygons` associated to their `GMSMutablePath` and their `Department`.

For example looping throw each departments from my JSON Dictionary, and `[rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)]` adding coordinate to my `GMSMutablePath`.

And so on for each department so that in the end I have my list of Polygons.

I have been struggling with JSON more than I would expected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get `Dictionary` you can loop through it and make `GMSMutablePath` from it.

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[myJSON dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions error:&error];
GMSMutablePath *rect = [GMSMutablePath path];
for(id key in json) {
    NSArray *coordinates = [json objectForKey:key];
    for(NSArray *coordinate in coordinates) {
        double latitude = [[coordinate firstObject] doubleValue];
        double longitude = [[coordinate lastObject] doubleValue];
        [rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)];
    }
}
// Create the polygon, and assign it to the map.
GMSPolygon *polygon = [GMSPolygon polygonWithPath:rect];
polygon.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.05];
polygon.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor];
polygon.strokeWidth = 2;
polygon.map = _mapView;
```

Comment: @RaphaelP. Welcome mate :)

Comment: @RaphaelP. Simply replace `array` to `coordinate` typo mistake :) I have edited answer also